# Start an animation when the other are finished

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I try to animate many element when the user click :

```
$('.serie').click(function(){
   $("#fade1").fadeIn( 2000);
   $("#fade2").fadeIn( 2000);
   $("#fade3").fadeIn( 3000);
   $('afterall').addClass( "newclass",700);
});
```

But my goal is that the addClass star when all other animation are finished.
I have try to set a queue:true to the addclass, but it doesn't work.

I know this syntax when there are just two actions :

```
$('#fade1).fadeIn('2000', function(){
    $('afterall').addClass( "newclass",700);
});
```

How do I do when there are several animations ?

Any idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: Check [`deferred.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use queue method of jquery. when you can list out of your animation function

check this : http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` to enqueue as much animations as you need.

```
var i=1;
var iv = setInterval(function(){
    if(i<4){
        $("#fade"+i).fadeIn(2000);
        i++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(iv);
    }
},2000);
```